# Reverse mathematics of Hilbert's Theorem 90

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, proof-theory, reverse-math

What is known, and what is published, on the reverse mathematics of the nest of results called [Hilbert's Theorem 90](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90)?

Comment: What is "reverse mathematics"?

Comment: @IgorRivin, reverse mathematics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) is an area of logic which measures the strength of theorems by comparing their logical strength over a weak base theory.

Comment: From Cris Conidis' research statement: "In the future I will examine and classify [in the setting of reverse mathematics] the number theoretic consequences of theorems from the (largely unexamined) number theoretic literature, such as Galois’ Theorem and Hilbert’s Theorem 90." His website: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~conidis/Chris_J._Conidis/Home.html

Comment: Since I didn't understand Jason Rule's definitions, I'll quote the wikipedia: "Reverse mathematics is a program in mathematical logic that seeks to determine which axioms are required to prove theorems of mathematics."

Comment: @anon, yes.  Sorry, for the unclear explanation.  It is called "reverse mathematics" because not only do you using the axioms to prove the theorems, you *use the theorems to prove the axioms (!)* (and thereby show they are the least axioms needed).

Comment: Theorem 90 is about finite cyclic extensions, so it's provable in $RCA_0$ (modulo some induction, which I don't expect). Kummer theorey might be much more interesting. Why are you interested in Theorem 90?

Comment: I expect you are right, and that the same argument works for  versions up to the non-commutative cohomology of general and special linear groups.  But as you say, induction is the point to check.

Comment: I am interested in it as a n example of cohomology pretty directly interpretable in PA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is provable in RCA<sub>0</sub> that if $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $F$ with Galois group $G$ then $H^1(G,L^\times)$ is trivial (every cocycle $a:G \to L^\times$ is a coboundary).

The finite Galois theory in RCA<sub>0</sub> was discussed by Friedman, Simpson and Smith in [*Countable algebra and set existence axioms*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072%2883%2990012-X) [APAL 25 (1983), 141–181; [MR0725732](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=725732)]. The executive summary is that finite Galois theory works fine in RCA<sub>0</sub>.

The usual proof of Theorem 90 works in RCA<sub>0</sub>. The linear independence of characters is provable using only $\Sigma^0_1$-induction since one can check linear dependence by testing at a fixed finite basis of $L$ over $K$. It follows that if $a:G \to L^\times$ is a cocycle then there is a $x \in L^\times$ such that $y = \sum_{\sigma \in G} a(\sigma)\sigma(x)$ is nonzero. Standard algebraic manipulations then show that $a(\sigma) = y/\sigma(y)$, i.e. $a$ is a coboundary.

Infinite Galois extensions are more subtle as discussed in [my paper with Jeff Hirst and Paul Shafer](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4944). For Theorem 90, it seems that the issue is a definitional one more than anything else.

If $K$ is an infinite Galois extension of $F$ such that $F$ is a subset of $K$ (as opposed to being merely embeddable in $K$) then the Galois group $G$ of $K$ over $F$ is a separably closed subgroup of permutations of $K$. Then $G$ can be represented as a complete separable metric space in the usual manner and one can make sense of the idea of a *continuous* cocycle $a:G \to L^\times$. In that scenario, RCA<sub>0</sub> does prove that $H^1(G,L^\times)$ is trivial since every continuous cocycle is a lifting of a cocycle from a finite Galois subextension.

In the general case where $F$ is merely embeddable in $K$, several issues arise. Galois theory still makes sense over WKL<sub>0</sub> but the Galois group $G$ is not necessarily separably closed. It is unclear what a continuous cocycle would be in that case. So the main issue is to define $H^1(G,L^\times)$ before proving anything about it. Note that this case is impossible in ACA<sub>0</sub> since we can always comprehend the range of an embedding. So, assuming ACA<sub>0</sub>, $H^1(G,L^\times)$ is always well defined and always trivial.